# Import a django app view in another app view

Tags: django, view, import

I have two django apps and I've called a view of app1 in app2, like this:

```
#app: app1
#someview.py

def a_view(request, someparam):
    #some code here


#app: app2
#otherview.py

from app1.someview import a_view

def another_view(request):
param = 1
a_view(request, param)

def view2(request):
  #some code
```

It works fine. My problem is that now I want to call a view from app2 in app1. So I add the import statement in someview.py like this:

```
#app: app1
    #someview.py
    from app2.otherview import view2

    def a_view(request, someparam):
        #some code here
```

The result is an ImportError "cannot import name view2".
Can anyone tell me why this happen?

Comment: Yes. I have it in both apps.

Comment: This is a import loop, this yelds for code refactoring

Answer (score 2):

The second import shadowing the first one ... Try like

```
import app2.otherview
```

or

```
from app2.views as app2_views
```

Comment: If I have a view in app2 (that generates a an app2 template) that I am importing into a view of app1, how would I then call that app2 view so that it is loaded in a `block` of an app1 template? I may be confused ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this because makes a loop.
You must add functions in another file and import in app1 and app2 separately.